# Converting a number with 000 and a -1 to its positive representation with only one 0

Tags: c#

> Read a list of non-negative integer values, sentinel `-1` (i.e. end the
>   program and display the output), and print the list replacing each
>    *sequence of zeros* with a *single zero*.

Example input

```
100044022000301-1
```

Then the output will be:

```
10440220301
```

the last problem of my list, I don't have a clue how to solve it, I tough in *removing the zeros* and transforming then in than adding a `0` after that

feels bad

Comment: Sequence means also 2 zeros?

Comment: a single one only, if there is more than 1 zero, then round it to one 0 only, it's pretty simple logic to fix it i`m lacking the tools I guess.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: *Linq* (in order to take the value before sentinel `-1`) and *Regular expressions* (turn `2` or more consequent `0` into single `0`):

given a `list` we can find out the last value before sentinel as

```
var value = list
  .TakeWhile(item => item != sentinel)
  .Last();
```

to turn two or more consequent `0` into single one we can use `Regex`:

```
string removed = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "0{2,}", "0");
```

**Code:**

```
// initial " list of non-negative integer values"
// I've declared it as long, since 100044022000301 > int.MaxValue 
List<long> list = new List<long>() {
  4555223,
  123,
  456,
  100044022000301L,  // we want this value (just before the sentinel)
 -1L,                // sentinel
  789,
};

long result = long.Parse(Regex.Replace(list
  .TakeWhile(item => item != -1) // up to sentinel
  .Last()                        // last value up to sentinel
  .ToString(),
   "0{2,}",                      // change two or more consequent 0 
   "0"));                        // into 0
```

Comment: _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_

Comment: really thanks Dmitry i just finished the solution with 5 lines of code and made it so much easier and elegant